# Jasmine does not Resolve Angular Promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am new to Jasmine.  I am trying to get my factory promise to resolve but it never seems to.

*Here is my factory which will retuirn a list of companies*

```
angular.module('commercial.factories').factory('companyFactory', companyFactory);

function companyFactory($http, $location, sessionStorage, config) {
    function getCompanies() {
        //call service and include company identifier in the service url
        return $http.get(wunUtils.constants.serviceBaseUrl + 'myCompanyService.svc/companies')
            .then(function(response) {
                return response.data;
            }, function(err){
                console.log(err);
            });
    }
});
```

*and my spec*

```
describe('company', function() {
beforeEach(module('mockedCommercial'));

var $httpBackend, companyFactory, $rootScope

beforeEach(function() {

    inject(function(_$httpBackend_, _$rootScope_, _companyFactory_) {
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
        companyFactory = _companyFactory_;
    });
})


it('should return available languages asynchronously', function() {


    $httpBackend.expectGET(/https:\/\/myDomain.com\/myCompanyService.svc\/companies+/)

        .respond(function(method, url, data, headers, params) {

            var response = {
                "data": [{
                    "address1": "Portsmouth",
                    "address2": null,
                    "city": "Portsmouth",
                    "contactEmail": "mocks@mocks.com",
                    "contactFirstName": "Mock",
                    "contactLastName": "Data",
                    "contactPhone": null,
                    "contactTitle": "Mr",
                    "country": "UK",
                    "fax": null,
                    "identifier": "c1xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
                    "location": "Portsmouth, UK",
                    "name": "Mock Company 1",
                    "phone": null,
                    "state": "Hampshire",
                    "zipCode": "PO19 3 EN"
                }, {
                    "address1": "Portsmouth",
                    "address2": null,
                    "city": "Portsmouth",
                    "contactEmail": "mocks@mocks.com",
                    "contactFirstName": "Test",
                    "contactLastName": "Test",
                    "contactPhone": null,
                    "contactTitle": "Mrs",
                    "country": "UK",
                    "fax": null,
                    "identifier": "c2xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
                    "location": "Portsmouth, UK",
                    "name": "Mock Company 2",
                    "phone": null,
                    "state": "Hampshire",
                    "zipCode": "Po9 3EN"
                }],
                "total": 2
            }

        });


    //--------------------------

    $rootScope.$digest();

    companyFactory.GetCompanies().then(function(result) {
        expect(result.hasOwnProperty('total')).toBe(true);
    })
});
});
```

As you can see i am using $rootScope.$digest to run the promise, however my expect is never hit so the test always passes.

I have read loads of different posts about this who all say this should work.  Am i doing something wrong here or have i missed some step?

### Edited - Simplified approach

So i simplified my question somewhat after looking at some more posts

Here is my new controller call...

```
        $scope.companies = [];
    var GetCompanies = function(options) {
        companyFactory.GetCompanies().then(function(response) {
            options.success(response);
            $scope.companies = response
        });
    }
$scope.GetCompanies = GetCompanies
```

my factory...

```
function getCompanies() {
    //call service and include company identifier in the service url
    return $http.get(wunUtils.constants.serviceBaseUrl + 'CompanyService.svc/companies')
        .then(function(response) {
            return response.data;
        }, function(err){
            console.log(err);
        });
}
    var service = {
    AddCompany: addCompany,
    GetCompany: getCompany,
    GetCompanies: getCompanies,
    GetUserCompanyFleets: getUserCompanyFleets,
    EditCompany: editCompany
};
```

and my new spec

```
describe('company', function() {
beforeEach(module('mockedCommercial'));

var $httpBackend, companyFactory, $rootScope, createController, scope

beforeEach(function() {

    inject(function($controller, _$httpBackend_, _$rootScope_, _companyFactory_) {
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
        scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
        companyFactory = _companyFactory_;
        createController = function() {
            return $controller('ManageCompaniesController', {
                '$scope': scope
            });
        };
    });
})


it('should return available languages asynchronously', function(done) {

    $httpBackend.whenGET(/https:\/\/myDomain.com\/V3_Fleet\/CompanyService.svc\/companies+/)

        .respond(function(method, url, data, headers, params) {
                return [{ 'id': 1 }];
            }
        });

    //--------------------------
    var dummy = [{ 'id': 1 }];

    createController();

    scope.GetCompanies()

    $httpBackend.flush()


    expect(scope.companies).toEqual(dummy)


    scope.$digest(); done()

});
```

});

Comment: did you solve your problem?

Comment: There's a syntax problem in your `companyFactory`. You're just declaring `GetCompanies` as a local function, not a method of the returned object.

Comment: Wouldn't you need to `return` the promise from the `it` callback?

Comment: please review my edits

Comment: Try calling `scope.$apply()` after `$httpBackend.flush()` to process the microtasks queued inside angular.

Comment: When i try this i get the following message from Karma 'Error: No pending request to flush! in ..."

Comment: @TimSmart for scope.apply or httpBackend.flush?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after much reading i found the answer by simplifying everything down.  I think my issues came from mixing **$httpBackend.flush()** and the **done()** function

What seems to happen is the the done() function triggers its own digest, so when trying to use the flush() function there is a conflict.

Here is my working factory.  Its a little different from my original purly as this was a more simple function to work with (less things to go wrong)

```
        function getUser(userId) {
        //call service and include user identifier in the service url
        return $http.get(wunUtils.constants.serviceBaseUrl + 'myService.svc/fleetusers/' + userId)
            .then(function(response) {
                return response.data;
            });
         }

        var service = {
        GetMe: getMe,
        GetUser: getUser,
        AddUser: addUser,
        EditUser: editUser,
        ActivateUser: activateUser
    };
```

and here is my simplified spec call the $httpBackend.Flush()

```
describe('Testing httpBackend', function() {

var $httpBackend;

beforeEach(module('mockedCommercial'));


beforeEach(inject(function(_$httpBackend_) {
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
}))

it('should behave...', function() {

    inject(function(userFactory, $rootScope) {

        var mockData = [];

        $httpBackend.expectGET(wunUtils.constants.serviceBaseUrl + 'FleetUserService.svc/fleetusers/10').respond(mockData);

        var promise = userFactory.GetUser(10);

        $httpBackend.flush();

        promise.then(function(result) {
            expect(result).toEqual(mockData);
        });

        });

});
});
```

**EDIT**

It should also be noted that when testing HTTPBackend the test will only work while using the expectGET and expectPOST as opposed to whenGET and whenPOST.

From what i can see, whenGet is used for mocking data while expectGet is used for testing mocks

Answer (score 0):

Try using `$httpBackend.flush()` before evaluating the test expectations.

This is the approach recommended by angular. For more details and examples, you can check the [documentation here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend#flushing-http-requests).

Comment: hey @boyomarinov i have tried this but still it does not resolve.  Please review the edit on my question

Answer (score 0):

You have two options when testing asynchronous code.

#### 1. Use synchronous mocks for everything

This includes:

- mock `$httpBackend`
- use `$timeout.flush()`
- use `$interval.flush()`
- use `scope.$apply()` to process leftover promises

And after all these you still cannot be entirely sure that all pending tasks have been processed, although its sufficient in 99.9% of the time.

#### 2. Make your tests asynchronous

Here you will have to make sure that every asynchronous controller method returns a promise, even if the returned promise is not used in the application. They will be used in tests.

Jasmine makes async testing pretty difficult but not impossible. You will have to use the [`done` callback](https://jasmine.github.io/edge/introduction#section-Asynchronous_Support), and code every asynchronous block like:

```
it('should...', function(done) {
    $q.when().then(function() {
        return $controller.GetSomething();
    }).then(function() {
        expect(scope.companies).toEqual(dummy);
    }).then(done, done.fail);
});
```

[**Mocha** handles proper asynchronous functions](http://mochajs.org/#working-with-promises) so you can write without `done`:

```
it('should...', function() {
    return $q.when().then(function() {
        return $controller.GetSomething();
    }).then(function() {
        expect(scope.companies).toEqual(dummy);
    });
});
```

Or even use `async-await` if you have the toolset:

```
it('should...', async () => {
    await $controller.GetSomething();
    expect(scope.companies).toEqual(dummy);
});
```